# batch rst2html conversion in a bash script

Tags: bash, restructuredtext

maybe a simple question for bash coders, but I'm not able to figure out this issue. 
I have multiple .rst files in multiple folders and sub-folders.

[image]

How can I create a script that converts all the .rst files in html (with the rst2html command) and creates new folder and sub-folders keeping the original structure?

Comment: where is `rst2html` command taken from ?

Comment: I just downloaded it with `apt-get install rst2html`

Comment: So you you are under UNIX environment?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.... Yes, using debian..

Answer (score 0):

You can first copy the entire hierarchy without the files (taken from this [link](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-copy-directory-structure-without-the-files-in-linux/)):

```
find /path/to/source -type d | cpio -pd /path/to/dest/
```

Then take every .rst file and convert it to .html with placing it in the dest directory

```
cd /path/to/source
find . -type f -name "*.rst" | while read f; do rst2html $f /path/to/dest/$f; done
```

[ Not the best manner to treat the result of command find, but it works :) ]